# Recaptcha with magento

Tags: php, magento, recaptcha

I have installed recaptcha in my client's site which is not live yet But in development. The recaptcha was working fine till last week but when I'm checking it now it gives a "Input error: Invalid referer " instead of the recaptcha block. 
I am just wondering what might be the cause of this. Is it something to do with the public and private key. ??
Any help would be appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yep! It's working for me, I manage over 3 different domains and I was trying to use the same recaptcha keys, I was getting this error " Input error: Invalid referer"

I just create new keys for each of my domains and It works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution its just to do with the public and private key.

For anyone who is having the same problem just go on this link http://www.google.com/recaptcha

and enter keys fro your domain or just 127.0.0.1 and it will work fine.

Cheers